# A function is real-differentiable iff it has a complex-differentiable extension

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives

Is this conjecture true?

> A function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is real differentiable at $a$ if and only if there exists a complex-differentiable function $g:A\to\Bbb C$ for some neighborhood of $a\in A\subseteq \Bbb C$ such that $f\Big|_{A\cap \Bbb R}=g\Big|_{\Bbb R\cap A}$.

The reverse implication is trivial; a complex differentiable function $g$ is real differentiable on $A$, and since differentiability is local and $f$ and $g$ agree on $A$, $f$ is real differentiable as well. But the forward implication is probably too strong to be true, although I can't think of any counterexamples. Is it true if $g$ is only required to be complex differentiable at $a$? If we only require $f-g\in o(x-a)$, then the statement can be satisfied by letting $g(z)=f(a)+f'(a)(z-a)$.

I'm interested in finding a characterization of real differentiability in terms of complex differentiability; other suggestions for definitional theorems of this sort are also welcome.

Comment: $f(x)=x|x|$ only has one derivative, analytic functions have infinitely many.

Comment: If $g$ is complex differentiable on a neighbourhood $A$ of $a$, then $f$ must be real-analytic in $A\cap\mathbb{R}$. You can find an extension $g$ that is complex differentiable _in_ $a$ when $f$ is real differentiable in $a$. But that's not particularly interesting.

Comment: @AdamHughes Why the edit to `\downharpoonright`? To me $\upharpoonright$ means function restriction, and $\downharpoonright$ means nothing.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro nvm my last comment; I misinterpreted what you were going for because of part of the wording.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand your comment. I see that requiring that $g$ be complex-differentiable *in a neighboorhood of* $a$ is too strong, because then $f$ is forced to be infinitely differentiable; but why is $g$ being complex-differentiable *at* $a$ uninteresting? Remember that my goal is to characterize the real-analysis weak notion of differentiability.

Comment: @AdamHughes I'm okay with the bar notation too. By the way $g|_{\Bbb R\cap A}=g|_{\Bbb R}$ because $A$ is the domain of $g$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I don't think you're wrong, but I don't know if you're exactly "right" either since that's a slightly shaky territory: usually it's best to just write exactly which set you mean since someone might read that and accidentally think you mean all of $\Bbb R$, and I've never actually seen someone use the convention for restriction, but I could see it as feasibly someone's convention.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You can always set $$g(z) = f(\operatorname{Re} z) + if'(a)\cdot \operatorname{Im} z = f'(a)\cdot(z-a) + \left(f(\operatorname{Re} z) - f'(a)\cdot(\operatorname{Re} z - a)\right).$$ A function being complex differentiable in a single point isn't very interesting, since that has no far-reaching consequences, like complex differentiability on an open set has.

Comment: @AdamHughes Note that the same argument applies to $f$, since $A\not\subseteq\Bbb R$ ($A$ is open and nonempty in the topology on $\Bbb C$, while $\Bbb R$ has no interior).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro what are you talking about?

Comment: @DanielFischer The only question that remains, then, is whether $g$ being complex differentiable only on the set $\Bbb R\cap A$ (which is open in $\Bbb R$, but not in $\Bbb C$) is enough to force analyticity. As far as I am aware, the theorem that holomorphic implies analytic only works if the set is open in $\Bbb C$, but your counterexample doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @AdamHughes If $g|_{\Bbb R}$ makes you uncomfortable since $\Bbb R\not\subseteq A$ (at least not necessarily), then $f|_A$ should as well since $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ and neither set is a subset of the other.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: This conjecture as written isn't even true if you replace complex by real. A function can be real differentiable at exactly one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(x)=x^2$ for $x$ rational, and $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational. Then f is differentiable at 0 but discontinuous at every other point, so it certainly cannot be complex differentiable on a neighborhood of 0.

Comment: Yeah, this has been a poor exercise in conjecture-making. It's more appropriate to have $f$ real-differentiable in a real neighborhood of $a$, although the conjecture is still false. The most enlightening version of this conjecture I've come up with is when $f$ is such and $g$ is complex differentiable only on the real line, in which case I think it is true for $g(z)=f(\Re z)+if'(\Re z)\Im z$.

Comment: The example below is differentiable on the entire real line.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Put $f(x) = x^2{\rm sgn}(x)$.  You are done right there.